# Solution for trading algorithm equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms

Do anybody know what does this equation means.?

[image]

I have seen this Kf coming above. But not downside.

Comment: where did you get it from?

Comment: I got it from a German project. I need to find what doe this means. @JonMarkPerry

Comment: On which topic? I found references to topology, plasma physics and money, but nothing tangible.